# Get parameters from two functions with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I have a program in which when a button is clicked, it changes its color. I have the following code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    MyButton btn = (MyButton)e.getSource();
    int x = getNew();
    if(x == 0) {
        btn.setType(0);
        btn.setColor(type0);
    }
    if(x == 1) {
        btn.setType(1);
        btn.setColor(type1);
    }
    if(x == 2) {
        btn.setType(2);
        btn.setColor(type2);
    }
}
```

I want to log the button and the new color it will have every time it is clicked, so I thought about exposing the parameter from actionPerformed and from setColor.

At every call to setColor from actionPerformed, I print the latter's argument. The pointcut and advice only for the new color:

```
public aspect Log {
pointcut change(Color c) : withincode(* actionPerformed(..)) && call(* *.setColor(..)) && args(c);

before(Color c) : change(c) {
    System.out.println("Chnging the color to " + c.toString());
}
```

}

It works. But I also want to take the event (so I can take the button and its old color). How could I accomplish this? It doesn't work with args(). Should I write another pointcut for actionPerformed()?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with 2 poincuts and 2 advices. I made another poincut to take the parameter from actionPerformed, using `execution`. This is the second poincut and advice:

```
pointcut change2(ActionEvent e) : execution(* *.actionPerformed(..)) && args(e);

before(ActionEvent e) : change2(e) {
    System.out.print("Changing from " + ((MyButton)e.getSource()).getColor().toString());
}
```